# Update status into input field

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Type a random email address into my form and notice the ajax updates at the top - http://goo.gl/DwvdY

How do I put those updates directly in the input box where you typed your email address? This is driving me crazy

There is an empty div named #response that first gets filled with this JS text update:

```
$('response').innerHTML = 'Adding email address...';
```

Then that same div gets the status returned to it and a newer update is echoed with PHP.

```
<span id="response">
<? require_once('inc/store.php'); if($_GET['submit']){ echo storeAddress(); } ?>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be:

```
$('#response').html('Adding email address...');
```

To store it the the textbox directly do this:

```
$('#email').val('Adding email address...');
```

This should do it:

```
$('#signup').submit(function() {
    // update user interface
    //store the value first to another variable before setting a new one
    var email = $("#email").val();

    $('#email').val('Adding email address...');

    // Prepare query string and send AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/store-address.php',
        data: 'ajax=true&email=' + escape(email),
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#email').val(msg);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks SO much! This site really helps me learn more as I get help with problems :)